# Having trouble to output arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms

I am asked to output two arrays in one label my code is as follow:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
  If block = True And counter <= 23 Then
    Try
      array1(counter) = TextBox1.Text
      Dim txtbox2 As String = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
      array2(counter) = txtbox2
      counter += 1
    Catch ex As Exception
      TextBox2.Text = ""
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  Dim arr1 As String
  Dim arr2 As String
  Dim result As String
  For Each values In array1
    arr1 = values
  Next

  For Each values In array2
    arr2 = values.ToString
  Next
  Label3.Text = String.Join("     ", arr1, arr2)
End Sub
```

when I click on the button it doesn't display all the values of the array it displays only the first one of each .  I am also trying to display it in a label kind of table view.

Comment: unless the first button is clicked more than once there will be only one value;  In the loop for the second click you are overwriting any previous value `arr2 = values.ToString` at the end it will just be the last value (in both cases). If you set a breakpoint and debug your code, you will learn a great deal. You should remove the Try/Catch so when there is an exception you are told about it and can fix the code

Comment: okay i will try that. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using `List(Of String)` instead of arrays, but with that being said, your String.Join is trying to merge two arrays, and it doesn't quite work like that.

Try adding your strings to a `List(Of String)` instead, then convert the entire output back into a single array:

```
Dim results As New List(Of String)(array1)
results.AddRange(array2)
Label3.Text = String.Join(" ", results.ToArray)
```

If your second array is an array of integers, you would have to convert them to an array of strings:

```
Dim results As New List(Of String)(array1)
results.AddRange(array2.Select(Function(x) x.ToString))
Label3.Text = String.Join(" ", results.ToArray)
```

Comment: i think that would work but my second array is an integer so it is not adding to List(Of String)

Comment: @Xtremfabz You didn't document your arrays very well.  Your posted code is mismatching it all over the place: `Dim txtbox2 As String = CInt(TextBox2.Text)` ???

Comment: yeah sorry for that i am new here and also not used to vb x) the textbox2 is for array2 which is integer

Comment: @Xtremfabz I updated the answer to accommodate the second array integers.